# Create color int from alpha, red, green, blue in Android

Tags: android, colors, argb

How do I create a color int from alpha, red, green, blue values (all from 0-255)?

I need this color int to set a view's background color.

I tried this:

```
    protected int colorStringToColor(String colorString){ // whereas colorString is i.e. "214+13+22+255" or "214+13+22+85"
        String[] comps = colorString.split("\\+");
        int myColor = 0;
        if(comps.length == 3){
            int a = 255;
            int r = Integer.parseInt(comps[0]);
            int g = Integer.parseInt(comps[1]);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(comps[2]);
            myColor = Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
        } else if (comps.length == 4){
            int a = Integer.parseInt(comps[3]);
            int r = Integer.parseInt(comps[0]);
            int g = Integer.parseInt(comps[1]);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(comps[2]);
            myColor = Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
        }
        return myColor;
    }
```

However, when I use the result for setting a views background color, both example colorString are of the same red???

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What it your expected output and what did you get?

Comment: have you checked your index value? you can reverse index value to get proper color value

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it by using the `argb(int red, int green, int blue)` method from [Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class like this :

```
int convertedColor= Color.argb(red, green, blue);
```

and set it into your view like this:

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(convertedColor);
```

Comment: Have you checked what are the values you are getting into an array? I think there is some issue with splitting.

Comment: Checked that, no issue

Comment: I've tried your example and it's working fine. It sets Red color with "214+13+22+255" string and "214+13+22+85" sets some other color like whitish orange color.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Color opaqueRed = Color.valueOf(0xffff0000); // from a color int
 Color translucentRed = Color.valueOf(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems you're not annotating the return value of the function by `@ColorInt`.

Change your function to

```
@ColorInt
private int colorStringToColor(){...};
```

Also, in your function, annotate

```
@ColorInt int myColor = 0;
```

Android has `android.graphics.Color` class, which provides methods to operate on Colors.

To get a `ColorInt` from ARGB values, you can use `Color.argb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue);`
method, which will return you corresponding `ColorInt` value.

You can find more about Color class from here

[android.graphics.Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color)

Comment: Check my updated answer, you must've forgot to annotate your function @mrd

Comment: Annotation did not help

Answer (score 0):

```java
int nonTransparentRed = Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This is the correct code to create the argb color. Make sure that String you are passing in is correct. to set the bg color you need to call setBackgroundColor on your view. Can you specify what exactly did not work? Color conversion or color set on view?

Comment: can you confirm that after the split you getting the values you are expecting?

Comment: splitting gets correct values. Color conversion did not work. Using Color.RED for or Color.BLUE works correctly.

Comment: Then it makes sense to ask if your view is not getting destroyed/redrawn after you are setting the color. also, are you sure that you get right reference to your view? Does it set wrong color or does it set color at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect there is no issue.

One thing is that, if you send this "214+13+22+85" value as integer then you will get the result value as the sum of these values. so may you have done mistake there.

```
import android.graphics.Color;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            textView = findViewById(R.id.txt);
            textView.setTextColor(colorStringToColor("214+13+22+235")); 
        }

        public int colorStringToColor(String colorString){ // whereas colorString is i.e. "214+13+22+255" or "214+13+22+85"
            String[] comps = colorString.split("\\+");
            int myColor = 0;
            if(comps.length == 3){
                int a = 255;
                int r = Integer.parseInt(comps[0]);
                int g = Integer.parseInt(comps[1]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(comps[2]);
                myColor = Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
            } else if (comps.length == 4){
                int a = Integer.parseInt(comps[3]);
                int r = Integer.parseInt(comps[0]);
                int g = Integer.parseInt(comps[1]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(comps[2]);
                myColor = Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
            }
            return myColor;
        }
```

I Implement your code in my project, and I checked it by well. What I saw there! It's working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead an agree with Prince here, your code is fine. But, also offer a theory. You are setting the view color and it's stripping the transparency. Check your numbers are they different? They should be. When you feed them into setBackgroundColor they are do the same thing. If I recall correctly it doesn't actually set the alpha. Try stripping off the alpha and using in `view.setAlpha(color>>24)` after  you set the color. Is that functionally different?

Prince is feeding it into setTextColor rather than setBackgroundColor.

```
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
view.setAlpha(color>>24);
```